# How do I cite my own words in APA format

Tags: citations

I know how to cite other's work in APA format, but how do I indicate that an idea, analysis, or comment is my own? For example:

"Outsourcing mundane tasks... (Smith, 98). A better method... (my words). In addition, you might... (Smith, 103)."

I also had a professor to cite ask me to cite a table that I created based on past experience.

I checked the APA guide, Purdue's APA guide, and eight other websites but was unable to find the answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who find this question and want an answer:

> If you cite or quote your previous work, treat yourself as the author and your own previous course work as an unpublished paper, as shown in the APA publication manual. For example, if Marie Briggs wanted to cite a paper she wrote at Walden in 2012, her citation might look like this:
>
> > Briggs (2012) asserted that previous literature on the psychology of tightrope walkers was faulty in that it "presumed that risk-taking behaviors align neatly with certain personality traits or disorders" (p. 4).
>
> And in the reference list:
>
> > Briggs, M. (2012). An analysis of personality theory. Unpublished manuscript, Walden University.
>
> If your original work contained citations from other sources, you will need to include those same citations in the new work as well, per APA. If Marie Briggs's earlier paper had cited Presley and Johnson, for example, it would look like this:
>
> > According to Briggs (2012), recent psychologists such as "Presley and Johnson (2009) too quickly attributed risk-taking to genetic factors, ignoring the social family issues that often influence the decision to explore pursuits such as tightrope walking" (p. 5).

According to https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/apa/citations/citingyourself: